# Object array with keys in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

We got an existing webservice that we attempt to document using Swagger. It often seems to return objects using:

```
schema:
    type: array
    items:
       $ref: '#/definitions/Tweets'
```

In this model the id of the tweet is in the Tweets definition. My returned output is formatted like this:

```
{  
   "127":{  
      "name":"Foo"
   },
   "110":{  
      "name":"Bar"
   }
}
```

Where the id is the key of the object. How do i do this is in Swagger?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `additionalProperties` (Ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#model-with-mapdictionary-properties)

Here is an example:

```
type: object
additionalProperties:
  $ref: '#/definitions/Tweets'
```

where Tweets has a property `name`

Comment: Just for clarification, the `additionalProperties` attribute basically means, there are additional properties in this object, not defined in `properties` and they have the defined schema....